# How to iterate simultaneously over two arrays using thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I have two arrays whose content I want to show in the same table (different columns). How can I iterate over the arrays using `index` or `th:each`

Here is what I want to achieve

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>List1Elm1</td>
        <td>List2Elm1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>List1Elm2</td>
        <td>List2Elm2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>List1Elm3</td>
        <td>List2Elm3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>List1Elm4</td>
        <td>List2Elm4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this List1Elm1 is the 1st element of list 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out there is no way to iterate over two lists simultaneously. So what one can do is iterate over the indices and the use the index to access the list.

```
<tr th:each="index : ${#numbers.sequence( 0, #arrays.length(List1)-1)}">
    <td th:text="${List1[index]>List1Elm1</td>
    <td th:text="${List2[index]>List2Elm1</td>
</tr>
```

**Note**: this will work only with `${...}` expressions and not with the `*{...}` expressions

Comment: missing the closing curly braces on lines 2 and 3. worked for me